# Print elements of a list to a .csv file

Tags: python, string, csv

I am reading in a csv file and dealing with each line as a list.  At the end, I'd like to reprint to a .csv file, but the lines aren't necessarily even.  I obviously cannot just go `"print row"`, since this will print it as a list.  How can I print it in .csv format?

Comment: what does your data structure look like that contains the data that you want to print?

Comment: It looks like a bunch of strings put together as a bunch of lists.. for example, [3123,SomeString, etc] [14, morestuff, etc, AB12DE] etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that "row" contains a list of strings, you could try using

```
print ",".join(row)
```

Answer (score 7):

Read manual, there's a CSV writer method (with example too). Don't print the data, store them and then write them into CSV file

http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: The CSV module is definitely your friend here. It was this module that made me understand what the “batteries included” bit of Python’s philosophy meant.

Answer (score 0):

Though it looks like your question was more towards *writing* to a csv file rather than printing it to standard output, here an example to do the latter using StringIO:

```
import StringIO
import csv

a_list_from_csv_file = [['for', 'bar'], [1, 2]]
out_fd = StringIO.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(out_fd, delimiter='|')
for row in a_list_from_csv_file:
    writer.writerow(row)
print out_fd.getvalue()
```

Like this you can use the different delimiters or escape characters as used by the csv you are reading.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by "the lines aren't necessarily even"? Are you using a homebrew CSV parser or are you using the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)?

If the former and there's nothing special you need to escape, you could try something like

```
print ",".join([ '"' + x.replace('"', '""') + '"' for x in row])
```

If you don't want ""s around each field, maybe make a function like `escape_field()` that checks if it needs to be wrapped in double quotes and/or escaped.